# OpenCv is pre-installed in google Colab, but i want to add one extra module from opencv_contrib. how to achieve this?

Tags: c++, opencv, google-colaboratory, opencv-contrib

I am working on google Colab and for the pre-installed opencv the functionality works fine, but i want to use "BRISQUE" which is not fully released but can be installed with opencv-contrib. There are methods which are followed but they are not for google colab. So not working for me.I actually want "quality" module from opencv-contrib to be appended to my opencv. The link to the module is https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/quality

Screenshot of sample program is attached which is giving error..

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The package you need is `opencv-contrib-python` and you can install it running `!pip install opencv-contrib-python`.

Comment: when i run !pip install opencv-contrib-python, it shows Requirement already satisfied. But the result i want is to use the quality module of opencv-contrib, which still gives error. the hider file quality.hpp is unknown to google colab. @marcoromelli

Comment: You can't run C++ code in Google Colab. You have to use Python.

Comment: That isn't true @marcoromelli . As i had successfully done a few. This is one of the few links you could try on google colab "https://www.wikihow.com/Run-CUDA-C-or-C%2B%2B-on-Jupyter-(Google-Colab)"
you can run c++ code by putting %cu on top of the Cell

Comment: Ok so it doesn't make sense to install `opencv-contrib-python`. I guess you'll have to recompile OpenCV from source including the "contrib" module: https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

Comment: @marcoromelli, I tried many methods, one of which was to 
1) download opencv latest from gethub,
2) extract it and then make an empty folder name build inside it
3)then download opencv-contrib from get hub and extract it. 
4)then configure and build opencv-contrib modules inside build directory,

I did all these, and build was also successful, and i can see the module i wanted in opencv/build/module
but when i try header of  that module #include<opencv2/quality.hpp>. i still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

```
!pip install  opencv-python==3.4.2.17
!pip install  opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.17
import cv2
```

this worked for me. Load cv2 in the same cell. IF you load seperately, it takes a default version